# Lambda function failing with /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.18' not found

Tags: python-3.6, aws-lambda-layers, simple-salesforce

I am trying to create a layer of simple-salesforce (Python Library) in AWS lambda, and trying to use it  (import it) from my python code. I am having windows machine.

Though I read that there might be issues due to compilation windows so I install ubuntu1804 from windows store and then went ahead with creating zip for lambda layers. (zip is created for python folder with structure "python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/......")

I am using Python 3.6. I went through few articles for this issue but could find any resolution. [this Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cz8QjmgfGHc&ab_channel=NKTStudios) helped me creating a layer for Pandas  & requests in AWS successfully with minor tweaks in pip commands I used

```
sudo python3 -m pip install simple-salesforce -t build/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages
```

Exactly same process i used for Simple salesforce and I am getting below error is as below:

Unable to import module 'lambda_function': /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.18' not found (required by /opt/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cryptography/hazmat/bindings/_rust.abi3.so)

Edit: --
Another approach I tried using .whl though this was not giving above error but giving error as "request module not found" and when I add request module layer it gives error authlib not found. (request layers work fine if I comment salesforce related things. Even tried uploading as simple layer same authlib issue I got)

Edit :
Lambda code I am using is  as below

```
the code I am using is basic code which doesnt have any logic with empty imports

import json
import pandas as pd
import requests as req
from simple_salesforce.format import format_soql

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    #TODO
```

Comment: I also experience the same error when using python3.7 runtime on AWS Lambda.

Comment: can you provide the imports and you lambda functions here?

Comment: I have updated the post with the code I am using, though it's just an empty function with imports.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed my code to not use simple_salesforce library and work out all the logic with Requests ( using Salesforce REST APIs).
This is not really ideal but I could get it working as I had some deliveries to meet.

Answer (score 7):

I also received the same error while installing pysftp on lambda which uses cryptography library(python)
the error was similiar to (required by /opt/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cryptography/hazmat/bindings/_rust.abi3.so)

The solution that worked for me is
1] pip uninstall cryptography
2] pip install cryptography==3.4.8
The following github link explains it in detail
https://github.com/pyca/cryptography/issues/6390

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Great answer, fixed the issue instantly :)

Comment: this did not work for me unfortunately for python 3.9

Answer (score 5):

AWS lambda functions are like virtual environments, they do not come with the `.so` files which are kernel level packages. When installing the python packages you have to make sure the system dependent files are installed with it. This can be achieved by passing the argument `--platform` to `pip install`.

From AWS post [How do I add Python packages with compiled binaries to my deployment package and make the package compatible with Lambda?](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/lambda-python-package-compatible/):

> To create a Lambda deployment package or layer that's compatible with Lambda Python runtimes when using pip outside of Linux operating system, run the pip install command with `manylinux2014` as the value for the `--platform` parameter.

```
pip install \
    --platform manylinux2014_x86_64 \
    --target=my-lambda-function \
    --implementation cp \
    --python 3.9 \
    --only-binary=:all: --upgrade \
    simple-salesforce
```

Answer (score 2):

Adding these to requirements.txt worked for me

```
bcrypt==3.2.2
cryptography==3.4.8
```