# Error: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.28' not found (required by /var/task/cryptography/hazmat/bindings/_rust.abi3.so)

Tags: python, aws-lambda

I need a 'for dummies' answer to this question that I know has been asked before.

We're using the Serverless framework for an AWS-hosted application. `Runtime=python3.8`  Got a nice big yml file that includes 16 functions, 2 of which include layers for Cryptography and for PyNaCl, which we bring in from here - https://github.com/keithrozario/Klayers and have used successfully for quite a while.

Last week, I needed to update a different function, which meant re-testing, which meant finding there's a newer version of the cryptography layer, so I updated it to have Cyptography v.39. Now I have a function that fails with the error, `` /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.28' not found (required by /var/task/cryptography/hazmat/bindings/_rust.abi3.so) `` This function hasn't been used since 07/2022, at which time it was just fine. Apparently it's also been that long since we redeployed from Serverless.

Attempts to fix:

- I reverted to the previous Cryptography layer; no difference
- I found an SO answer with this link https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/lambda-python-package-compatible/, followed that guide to change my local install and also to make my own layer and attach it in the console; no difference
- Another SO answer led me here - https://github.com/pyca/cryptography/issues/6390, which then goes to https://github.com/pyca/cryptography/issues/6391, which also didn't help
- Today, I found this link https://repost.aws/questions/QU85KE-2hPQ4KDQyByKV_WIw/creating-a-lambda-zip-package-that-runs-python-package-cryptography and the OP says they had to make all of their lambdas from x86_64 to arm64, even if those functions weren't using Cryptography.  That's seems insane, and besides.... how??

This question [Lambda function failing with /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.18' not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69475140/lambda-function-failing-with-lib64-libc-so-6-version-glibc-2-18-not-found) includes the advice to move from Cryptography v.39 all the way back to v.3.4.7 (from 03/2021), which seems like bad advice.  Surely the 14 updates between those 2 versions include some important changes.

I'm at a loss. I feel like I'm just running in circles, and meanwhile can't make progress on the actual function I'm trying to update because this is such a block.

Comment: Short form: Compile the software you're using for the platform you're using. This comes from using a package built for an older distro on a newer one.

Comment: If you want tooling that isn't prone to this class of problem at all, think about installing your dependencies via [Nix](https://nixos.org/), which _never_ reuses software inappropriately: if you want to use program-Y and the available binaries aren't compiled against the same glibc as the rest of your system, Nix will either install an older glibc that program-Y was built against (only for use by program-Y, with everything else still continuing to use the libc that other software was built against), or rebuild program-Y against your newer glibc.

Comment: BTW, glib and glibc are two different things; I'm removing the glib tag, since it's the latter that's relevant here.

Answer (score 7):

I'm using Serverless and https://www.npmjs.com/package/serverless-python-requirements to bundle a Python 3.9 function, and was hitting the same error. I added a couple of pip args to the serverless plugin to specify the target system, which got me past the issue:
`pipCmdExtraArgs: ['--platform manylinux2014_x86_64', '--only-binary=:all:']`
Here is the full config I'm using for the plugin (from my serverless.ts):

```
pythonRequirements: {
      dockerizePip: false,
      usePoetry: false,
      layer: true,
      useDownloadCache: false,
      useStaticCache: false,
      pipCmdExtraArgs: ['--platform manylinux2014_x86_64', '--only-binary=:all:'],
      slim: true
    }
```

which results in a pip install command that looks like this (just in case you are calling pip install manually in your pipeline):
`python3.9 -m pip install --platform manylinux2014_x86_64 --only-binary=:all: -t /someOutputFolder -r requirements.txt`

Update: Another option I've found is to use a docker container as the lambda container, and install the python dependencies in the dockerfile, as shown in these docs: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/images-create.html
Serverless makes it really easy to deploy the container image: https://www.serverless.com/blog/container-support-for-lambda

Comment: This answer solved my issue - those both, additional parameters were necessary. Although, I've been using `pip` command directly: `pip install --platform manylinux2014_x86_64 --only-binary=:all: --upgrade -t python oracledb`

Comment: https://repost.aws/knowledge-center/lambda-python-package-compatible

this solve my issue

Answer (score -1):

I was able to address this issue by taking the following steps:

Download [invoke-x.x.x.tar.gz](https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/f9/42/127e6d792884ab860defc3f4d80a8f9812e48ace584ffc5a346de58cdc6c/invoke-2.2.0.tar.gz) from [PyPi](https://pypi.org/project/invoke/#files).

Extract the contents of the package and locate the invoke folder.

Place the invoke folder in a directory where your requirements.txt file is present.

Integrate the following code snippet at the beginning of your script:

```
from invoke import run
cmd = "pip install --target /tmp -r requirements.txt"
result = run(cmd, hide=False, warn=False)
import pathlib
import sys
temp_dir = pathlib.Path('/tmp')
sys.path.insert(0, temp_dir.absolute().as_posix())
```

By following these steps, the required dependencies will be installed directly from your script. This approach is likely to resolve the issue you encountered. Consequently, you'll then be able to utilize your script along with the invoke package folder and requirements.txt for installing packages in various serverless service providers as well.

Comment: Please don't post the same answer at multiple questions. If you think that they duplicate each other, choose one and flag the others as duplicates