# Unable to import module 'lambda_function': /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.28' not found

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, paramiko

I'm trying to execute a lambda function that uses paramiko library. However, I'm unable to "Unable to import module 'lambda_function': /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.28' not found". I was able to pip3 install paramiko, zipped the file and sent to my s3 bucket.

The python run time is 3.9 for my lambda function and 3.9 is the version of python in the zip file. I created a lambda layer and assigned it to the lambda function. However, its not able to recognize paramiko on the import statement.

What else am I missing?

below is an image of the structure of my folder. thanks in advance. How can I get paramiko lib imported successfully?

[image]

Lambda function response:

```
Response
{
  "errorMessage": "Unable to import module 'lambda_function': /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.28' not found (required by /opt/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/cryptography/hazmat/bindings/_rust.abi3.so)",
  "errorType": "Runtime.ImportModuleError",
  "stackTrace": []
}
```

Comment: You have to create your lambda layer using docker image, which will have proper glib.

Comment: The error message looks pretty similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75389710/error-lib64-libc-so-6-version-glibc-2-28-not-found-required-by-var-task-c) or [another one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75472308/aws-lambda-returns-lib64-libc-so-6-version-glibc-2-28-not-found). Have you tried using the suggested approach by installing the packages using the command `python3.9 -m pip install --platform manylinux2014_x86_64 --only-binary=:all:  <package>` instead?